# Reference an issue in commit

Tags: git, bitbucket

How can I reference an issue when committing to Bitbucket?

I haven't used Bitbucket much, but I know you can defiantly do this in github:

[image: github reference]

Answer (score 1):

Just write `issue #NUMBER` in a (commit) message/comment.

See https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Mark+up+comments,+issues,+and+commit+messages

Comment: Additionally if you want to reference a commit in the issue tracker you only need to copy and paste the hash.

Comment: you can put many lines in a commit messages, do not worry about the length of the message, and focus on the quality.